# What is wag-service?

Tags: wireshark

Does anyone know what wag-service is?

I'm seeing it a lot in Wireshark

Comment: It's the FBI tracking you down. Run for the hills!

Comment: See my answer on serverfault.

Comment: @joeqwerty, a link to the item on serverfault would be hot.

@intransit, generally speaking, you can find the *port number* when Wireshark gives a service name, by searching /etc/services (*nix) or %windir%\system32\drivers\etc\services (Windoze). I've seen too many instances where the service name was confusing, but the port number immediately maps to something I know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a protocol running on port 2608/tcp. If you have the MAC address, then you can find the network equipment that generate these packets and infer the use.